# This code keeps returning Ball is not defined

Tags: javascript, class, new-operator, p5.js

```
let ball;

// declared 

function setup(){

  createCanvas(500, 500); 

  ball = new  Ball ();
  // this is the problem keeps saying ball is not defined
  // i have defined it
  // can anyone point out the mistake
}
function draw(){
  background(0);
  class Ball{
    constructor(){
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You might consider using consistent indentation when writing code - it'll make reading and debugging it much easier, not only for potential answerers, but for you as well, when we can all see the `{` `}` blocks and their nesting level at a glance, rather than having to carefully pick through each line just to pick up on the logical paths.

Comment: While @CertainPerformance was writing that comment I was editing your question to apply appropriate indentation (I changed only white-space). With consistent indentation you can see immediately that that class is defined inside the `draw()` function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From what I can tell, your `Ball` class is **inside** your `draw()` function. You probably want it to be outside. Something like this:

```
let ball;

function setup(){
  createCanvas(500, 500);
  ball = new  Ball ();
}

function draw(){
  background(0);
}

class Ball{
  constructor(){
  }
}
```

Note that **proper indentation** can help you spot errors like this.

Comment: Thank you, i'm so grateful, turns out that was the problem and not because i didn't define it. thanks